# giving a program the same input file 100 times

Tags: linux, bash, file, input, file-io

So I have this line-script:

```
head -n5 numbers.txt | ./ex2-2
```

and I want ex2-2 to get as an input the first five lines of numbers.txt 100 times.

ex2-2 is a program that gets as an input `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5`

Thanks in advance! 
(Please keep the answer in one line, because I my task includes finding an answer with one line)

Comment: Twice, or 100 times? These are going to have very different answers -- in the "twice" case someone could just run `head` twice; in the 100x case, it would make more sense to cache the output.

Comment: 100 times, sorry about the confusion

Comment: BTW, *usually*, we expect you to show your own attempt and how it failed, rather than asking folks to build something for you for scratch / from spec. See the docs on building a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code example that demonstrates a bug.

Answer (score 1):

one-liner without loops

```
$ input=$(head -n 5 numbers.txt); printf "${input}\n%.0s" {1..100} | ...
```

as requested...

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR<6{a=a sep $0; sep=ORS} END{for(i=1;i<=100;i++) print a}' numbers.txt | ...
```

or if the input file is long, you can short-circuit

```
$ awk '{a=a sep $0; sep=ORS} NR==6{exit} END{for(i=1;i<5;i++) print a}' numbers.txt | ...
```

Comment: What? No *"awk to the rescue"* ? ;-) Nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
export input=$(head -n 5 numbers.txt)
parallel -N 0 'echo "$input"' ::: {1..100}
```

Or, all in one line:

```
export input=$(head -n 5 numbers.txt); parallel -N0 'echo "$input"' ::: {1..100}
```

Or, even shorter, but less efficient:

```
parallel -N0 head -n 5 numbers.txt ::: {0..99}
```

Comment: `parallel -qN 0 echo "$(head -n5 numbers.txt)" ::: {1..100}`

Answer (score 0):

Capturing the content and repeating it with a loop makes sense:

```
input=$(head -n 5 numbers.txt)
max=100

for ((i=0; i<max; i++)); do
  printf '%s\n' "$input"
done | ./ex2-2
```

As a one-liner, one just adds semicolons in place of whitespace:

```
input=$(head -n 5 numbers.txt); max=100; for ((i=0; i<max; i++)); do printf '%s\n' "$input"; done | ./ex2-2
```